# Drag and drop different shaped over an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing one task and in that I want to drag and drop the different dynamically shaped [like : circle, rectangle, oval, etc] over an image. Like

[image]

In this picture you can see that how the rectangle shape has drag and drop over an image. This type of features I want in my task. I have search this features in many websites but nothing I have to seen which I want. So is there any jquery plugin or any javascript then please suggest me or give me some hint.

Advance In Thanks.

Comment: have you even tried implementing anything yet? we're here to help with your code issues, not provide suggestions on cool plugins to use.

Comment: you can use jQuery UI droppable, here is an example  [link](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager)

Comment: @aje I want to draw different shaped over an image by doing drag and drop. But in your example there is no shaped anywhere.